# Why is the join fun not working in this pass gen in python?

Tags: python

i was trying to build a pass gen and the join is not working i would like to know why?

```
def psswd_gen():
    import random
    import string
    passwd=[]
    alplo = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    alpup = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    num1 = list(range(10))
    allto= alplo + alpup + num1
    paswlen=(int(input("Hello, this is the password generator, how long would you like your password to be? ")))
    if paswlen < 6:
        paswlen = (int(input("Please enter a number greater than 6 ")))
    elif paswlen >=6:
        passwd = str(random.choices(allto, k=paswlen))

    return "".join(passwd)
nw = psswd_gen()
print(nw)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please properly format your code by using "{}" button

Comment: "and the join is not working" **how is it not working exactly**? What is the  actual output? What is the expected output? Please always provide a [mcve] with a full problem specification. If you are getting errors, please provide the full error message including the stack trace.

Comment: It is not clear how `join` is supposed to work at all. In some cases, `passwd` is an empty list. In some other cases, it is a string. In either case, your code makes no sense.

Comment: why do you even work with lists here?

Comment: Sorry. Im new on this forum. It's not working because it prints a list. This is the output =['r', 't', 'd', 'd', 'v', 'o', 4]

Comment: @CesilioSantana what's the output of passwd?

Comment: If you look at `type(nw)` you will see it isn't a list at all... `.join` is working. You *really* need to do some basic debugging, though, like adding `print` to see what the values are in your variables at various points. For example, try `print(passwd)` before `return ''.join(passwd)`...

Comment: the output is = ['r', 't', 'd', 'd', 'v', 'o', 4] or something like that. i know type(nw) says it is a string but it does look more like a list to me

Comment: If it says `string`, then it's a string. It looks like a list, because you have a string that contains a sequence of characters, that would also be printed if you printed a list. It is still a string, though

Comment: So what do i need to do get the output like = rtddvo4 and not = ['r', 't', 'd', 'd', 'v', 'o', 4] like im getting it right now

Comment: See my answer below, which somehow got downvoted

Answer (score 0):

The function returns that string of a list, because:

```
>>> str([1,2,3])
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

What you want is

```
import random
import string

def psswd_gen():
    allto = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

    paswlen = int(input("Hello, this is the password generator, how long would you like your password to be? "))
    while paswlen < 6:
        paswlen = int(input("Please enter a number greater than 6 "))
    passwd = random.choices(allto, k=paswlen)

    return "".join(passwd)
nw = psswd_gen()
print(nw)
```

EDIT: What you were doing is converting the list to a string, which -- as I have shown above -- will give you a string. As the string is an iterable it can be joined, but joining a string on an empty string just returns the string.

What I have done is: I did not convert the list to a string. You should really learn to use a debugger, which would make these errors obvious

Comment: passwd = random.choices(allto, k=paswlen)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @CesilioSantana oh sorry, there was an extra parenthesis I overlooked. Should work now

Comment: The line

  paswlen = (int(input("Please enter a number greater than 6 ")) is missing a closing bracket. I cannot edit it so it is good to note.

Comment: It is working now!!. Thanks for the help. Can you tell me what was i doing wrong. Your "".join is working and mine did not.